# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: UserDaoImpl [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am developing a Spring 3.0.2 based project. From last three days it is showing the below error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: UserDaoImpl [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

How do I solve this error?

My applicationContext file is:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

        <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
        <context:component-scan base-package="web"/>
<!--        <import resource="appicationContext.xml"/>        -->

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />  

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />


        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="hibernatefiles.HibernateUtil" factory-method="getSessionFactory"/>           

        <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
                <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="userDaoImpl"  class="dao.UserDaoImpl"/>

        <bean id = "profiler" class = "Profiler.AspectProfiler" />

     <bean name="/userRegistration.htm" class="web.UserController" depends-on="userDaoImpl">
            <property name="userDaoImpl" ref="userDaoImp"/>       
     </bean>       
</beans>
```

The stack trace is:

```
   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file [D:\JAVA Stuffs\projects\NewSpringDemo\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\web\UserController.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: **UserDaoImpl [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]**
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    root cause

    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: UserDaoImpl [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
        org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:315)
        org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:204)
        org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:191)
        org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:172)
        org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:200)
        org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:254)
        org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:286)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1418)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
...
```

The userDaoImpl is autowired in UserController class which is annotated with @Controller:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package web;

import dao.UserDaoImpl;
import domain.UsersTable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 *
 * @author amit
 */

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/userRegistration.htm")
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDaoImpl userDaoImpl;

    public UserDaoImpl getUserDaoImpl() {
        return userDaoImpl;
    }

    public void setUserDaoImpl(UserDaoImpl userDaoImpl) {
        this.userDaoImpl = userDaoImpl;
    }   

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println("Get request found. . . . *****************************");
        UsersTable user = new UsersTable();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "registrationForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView OnSubmit(@ModelAttribute("user") UsersTable user) {
        System.out.println("User Object is : "+user);
        userDaoImpl.saveUser(user);
        return new ModelAndView("userConfirm", "user", user);
    }
}
```

Aspect Profiler:

```
package Profiler;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class AspectProfiler {
   @Pointcut("execution(* UserDaoImpl.mySave())")
            public void insertionProfiler(){ }

    @Around("insertionProfiler()")
            public void aroundInsertionProfiler(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable{
            System.out.println("Before Insertion....");
            pjp.proceed();
            System.out.println("After saving the data I am back.");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post also the part of code where you defined your pointcuts, I believe it's this AspectProfiler?

Comment: So now which error message you are facing?

Comment: "UseDaoImpl is not available for the creation of userController....."

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why this old question popped up on my RSS feed today, but just for the record, the correct answer is that in annotation-style AspectJ pointcuts you need to use fully-qualified class names ***including package name***, i.e. the pointcut should be

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* dao.UserDaoImpl.mySave())")
```

That is what `[Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]` implies in the first place.

I wonder why nobody else noticed that back in 2011.

---

**Update:** There is one case in which you might not need to specify a fully qualified class name (FQCN): if the aspect happens to be in the exact same package as the class or annotation used in the pointcut. But that is fragile because if you ever refactor, moving around classes between packages, the aspect would still compile but its behaviour break. So you better use FQCN and let your IDE help you refactor class and package name changes in sync with aspects.

Comment: @kriegaex it helped me with Spring Webflux but before it was working without specifying fully qualified name

Comment: If it was working before, maybe you were using native AspectJ syntax instead of annotation-based one. There you can just use imported class names. Or you had a pointcut like `execution(* mySave()))` without any package name and then changed it into something like `execution(* dao.UserDaoImpl.mySave())`, so now you need the fully qualified name.

Answer (score 2):

Are the spaces between annotation. and the class names in

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation. DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation. AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
```

only a copy paste error here or are they really in your xml? If so, then remove them and try again.

Comment: it was my mistake buddy... thanks ... but there are still errors I have edited the question please see....

Answer (score 1):

Your `UserController` has **@Autowired** property named `UserDaoImpl`. This is invalid, it should be `userDaoImpl`

Comment: After reading stack trace I see that AspectJ Weaver has the problem with finding the class UserDaoImpl...

Comment: I think you need first to attach the code where you configure AspectJ pointcuts. I think somewhere there you use "UserDaoImpl" and instead you need to use "dao.UserDaoImpl"

Comment: could you try to prepend pointcut expression UserDaoImpl.mySave() with "dao." and try again? I think you need exact location of your bean to correctly configure pointcut (for example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/AllKindsOfPointcut.htm)

Comment: for the sake of trying... I just tried but it didnt help... exact path is not necessary '*' does the work ... I have written the same kind of profiler so many times and it works.... this time however the problem starts while autowiring the userDaoImpl to userController.... I think I missed something in applicationContext... or some jars are playing prank with me...

Comment: hmm, that star should be for declaring return value of methods to be intercepted,not for the place where mySave() is expected. I stronly believe that pointcut is where the issue is, the controller can't be created because of cascade failure of bean creation

Answer (score 0):

You lost "l", it should be "userDaoImpl".